# How to have examples in @Parameter in OpenAPI (Swagger) in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am wanting to essentially replicate a `@RequestBody` with `@Parameter`. I found this in Swagger documentation: "Also without a `@RequestBody` annotated parameter and with no `@RequestBody` annotation at method level or as field of Operation#requestBody, if a parameter is annotated with `@Parameter` with no in field specified and no JAX-RS annotation (`@QueryParam`, `@HeaderParam`, `@BeanParam`), the parameter is resolved as a request body."

My use case is that I have an annotation that will be used across many microservices, so we want to define it once in our common library. Spring does not pick up `@RequestBody` as a meta-annotation, while `@Parameter` is picked up. Essentially, I am trying to use `@Parameter` as an `@RequestBody`.

My code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Parameter(
        in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT,
        description = "Dynamic query string that will be used to query/filter this resource.",
        required = true,
        examples = {
                @ExampleObject(
                        name = "example1",
                        summary = "Search for a...",
                        value = "hello==4567*",
                        description = "blah"
                ),
                @ExampleObject(
                        name = "example2",
                        summary = "samplee",
                        value = "hello==John*",
                        description = "blahhh"
                )
        },
        schema = @Schema(
                description = "Query Field and Value",
                name = "Query",
                allowableValues = {"query"})
)
public @interface Query {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

This works so far EXCEPT for the `examples =`. It does work with `@RequestBody`, but not with `@Parameter`. How can I get `@ExampleObject` or something similar work with `@Parameter`? `example =`  does work, but it doesn't have the same toggle option `examples` gives. We are using OpenAPI 3.0.

Thanks so much.